# How DBConnectionPool will behave during Connection reset

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

In our project we are maintaining our own DB connection pool.  
For resolving the issue `'java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception` most of people has suggested to use standard connection pool like apache dbcp.

- I am wondering what is the logic those standard pooling mechanism will perform during connection reset?
- How do DBConnectionPool know that DB connection has timed out? since we know conn.isClosed() won't help here.
- Is it each db connection will have one tcp client socket with DB server?
- Finally is it advisable; whenever i return the connection to the pool; pool should close the connection; if the connection is existing more than ~10 mins from it is returned?
  [~10 mins server side conn timeout variable]

Kindly answer all my questions.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this question assuming that you made use of Apache DBCP for connection pooling by using `org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool`, `org.apache.commons.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory`, `org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory` and `org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource` classes.

- I am wondering what is the logic those standard pooling mechanism
  will perform during connection reset?
  **If `GenericObjectPool.testOnBorrow` and `GenericObjectPool.testOnReturn` are set true to The Connection will be validated whether it is active or not using a `validationQuery` set in `PoolableConnectionFactory`. If the validation is failed the Connection object is dropped and new one is created and added to the pool**
- How do DBConnectionPool know that DB connection has timed out? since
  we know conn.isClosed() won't help here. **Same mechanism as above**
- Is it each db connection will have one tcp client socket with DB
  server? **Yes**
- Finally is it advisable; whenever i return the connection to the
  pool; pool should close the connection; if the connection is existing
  more than ~10 mins from it is created? [~10 mins server side conn
  timeout variable] **If you think it should will not create unneccessary network traffic and if you have special reason to do that. You can do it. By setting `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` in `GenericObjectPool` along with `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` if you want to remove based on idle time**

Comment: You mean to say whenever a new connection is requested; the pool will perform a test query (validationQuery) execution on DB to verify the TCP status. If the query is successful then pool will return that connection ??

Comment: You are not in control of new Connections if you are using a DB Pool. It is upto the pool to decide when to create new Connections. But as the answer to first question explains testOnBorrow and testOnReturn can be used to validate status of existing connections before they are given to the user.

Comment: Check these Lines http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/dbcp/PoolableConnectionFactory.html#line.632 and http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/dbcp/PoolableConnectionFactory.html#line.645

validateObject is called which is turn validateConnection which executes the validationQuery using a JDBC statement. If SQL execution failed (Due to Connection Loss, Time-out, Network Congestion) or validationQuery failed to return a result the validateObject will return false which means the connection is invalid.

Comment: +1. Thank You! Then my first comment is valid rit??, In my customized pool; i should also maintain a validation query execution before returning the connection to the applications from my pool?